# Get Value From Dynamic ID of Button on Click in Javascript

Tags: javascript, java, html

My .js File contains

```
function ngForEducationDetails() {
        let value = '';
        educationdetails.forEach((x , i) => {
        value += 
      `<div class=""> <p class="f-14 details-subheaders"> ${x.institutename} 
      <button class="edit-icon xd" style="float: right" id="editSingleEducation" value="${i}"> </button> 
      <p class="f-12">${x.fieldofstudy} </p> 
      <p class="f-12 mb-4"> ${x.startdate} - ${x.enddate} </p> </div>` ;
    });

    document.getElementById('fos').innerHTML = value; };

    ngForEducationDetails();
```

in my html file i have

```
 <span for="fos" id ="exd" class="col-12"></span>
```

I want that on Button Click , i want the value of id assocciated with it . 
The Below function doesnt work . Help me :)

```
  document.getElementById('editSingleEducation').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var indexvalue = document.getElementById('editSingleEducation').value
  console.log(indexvalue , "indexvalue")
     })
```

NOTE : i cant use Inline Function as im doing it in chrome Extension and chrome extension wont allow it

Comment: It is the Id for the Button , which has value in it

Comment: So how do i get the Value "?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You are looping so more than one of the same ID? That is not allowed
2. Delegate

---

```
document.getElementById('fos').addEventListener("click",function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.classList.contains("edit-icon")) {
    console.log(tgt.value);
  }
})
```

Improved code, using the id in a data attribute:

```js
const educationdetails = [{
    "candidateeducationid": 4,
    "institutename": "Mumbai University",
    "degree": "Bsc",
    "fieldofstudy": "Science",
    "startdate": "2019-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "enddate": "2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "score": null,
    "activities": null
  },
  {
    "candidateeducationid": 5,
    "institutename": "LA",
    "degree": "MCA",
    "fieldofstudy": "Science",
    "startdate": "2018-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "enddate": "2019-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "score": null,
    "activities": null
  },
  {
    "candidateeducationid": 6,
    "institutename": "Abu Dhabi University",
    "degree": "Associate of Arts and Sciences",
    "fieldofstudy": "Science",
    "startdate": "2018-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "enddate": "2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "score": null,
    "activities": null
  }
];

function ngForEducationDetails() {
  let value = educationdetails.map((x, i) => `<div class=""> <p class="f-14 details-subheaders"> ${x.institutename} 
          <button class="edit-icon xd editSingleEducation" data-id="${x.candidateeducationid}" style="float: right">${x.candidateeducationid}</button> 
          <p class="f-12">${x.fieldofstudy} </p> 
          <p class="f-12 mb-4"> ${x.startdate} - ${x.enddate} </p> </div>`);

  document.getElementById('fos').innerHTML = value.join("");
}


ngForEducationDetails()

document.getElementById('fos').addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.classList.contains("edit-icon")) {
    console.log(tgt.dataset.id);
  }
})
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="fos"></div>
```

Comment: Your "ngForEducationDetails()" function is not displaying the dynamic list .. where as console.log(document.getElementById('fos').innerHTML) is giving empty string

Comment: If you give me an example of the educationdetails, I can test

Comment: https://paste.laravel.io/bbc8918c-98cd-4795-a36e-86b906182cb9

Answer (score 0):

You should not have same id for multiple elements in the same html document and so your code should be

```
// also notice that only submit buttons can have a value attribute, and its not recommended to let them have values, better use a custom attribute if you want to retrieve it from code
function ngForEducationDetails() {
        let value = '';
        educationdetails.forEach((x , i) => {
        value += 
      `<div class=""> <p class="f-14 details-subheaders"> ${x.institutename} 
      <button class="edit-icon xd" style="float: right" id="editSingleEducation-${i}" data-index-value="${i}"> </button> 
      <p class="f-12">${x.fieldofstudy} </p> 
      <p class="f-12 mb-4"> ${x.startdate} - ${x.enddate} </p> </div>` ;
    });

    document.getElementById('fos').innerHTML = value; };

    ngForEducationDetails();


[...document.querySelectorAll('[id|=editSingleEducation]')].forEach(node => {
   node.addEventListener('click', 
    function(event) {
        // notice that getAttribute will return a string so you may want to parse result
        console.log(indexvalue , event.target.getAttribute('data-index-value')) 
     })
})
```

Comment: Delegation is much more elegant

Comment: @mplungjan yea sometimes it makes code shorter, however its easier to break later and harder to change, because you are delegating depending on the html structure. It also hard to know just looking at html that a certain css class is being used in code

Comment: Very rarely does the id of the container change. I stand by my recommendation to not add eventListeners to multiple identical elements - also to use the class `editSingleEducation` instead of ID

Answer (score 0):

- IDs meant to be unique for the whole document

You can't have multiple elements with the same IDs, it will break the function
`getElementById`

If you want quick fix, But I strongly advise against generating HTML inside you Javascript:

```
educationdetails.forEach((x , i) => {
    value +=
        `<div class=""> <p class="f-14 details-subheaders"> ${x.institutename} 
  <button onclick="clickMe(event)" data-id="${i}"> Click Me </button> 
  <p class="f-12">${x.fieldofstudy} </p> 
  <p class="f-12 mb-4"> ${x.startdate} - ${x.enddate} </p> </div>` ;
});

function clickMe(e)
{
    console.log(e.target.dataset.id);
}
```

If you are interested on making your code better you can use **templates** instead of typing your HTML code inside your Javascript file.

PS: try to avoid using innerHTML as it is to inject Javascript inside your HTML(XSS attack)

Resources:

- Using getElementById: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById
- Using Templates: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_template.asp
- XSS attach: https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/xss/

Comment: Thankx for the Help , bt i cant use clickme(event) on tag itself , as im doing it in Chrome Extension and it doesnt allow inline functions

Comment: Good to know. I will leave it here for anyone facing the same issue.